# Sending and Retrieving MySQL data asynchronous with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, asynchronous

I'm trying to create some kind of bot in C# that joins a webbrowser game and collects data and kicks banned people. I'm sending my data to a MySQL database so people can look up their data on a website.

I've tried to simplify my code as much as possible to better explain whats happening.

I've got an eventHandler that's being called when something happens ingame by a person, so this could be called exactly at the same time I believe.

```
//EventHandler
public static void OnMessage(object sender, InOutPlayerc.Message m)
{
    int id = m.getInt(0);

    switch (m.Type)
    {
        //If a player logged in (m = [id, name])
        case "login":
            Player p = loadPlayerSQL(m.getString(1));
            if(p.Status == "BANNED") {
                kickPlayer(p);
            }
            else {
                //Store the player local, this way 
                savePlayerLocal(id, p);
            }
            return;

        //If a player said something (m = [id, chatmessage])
        case "talk":
            addTimesTalked(loadPlayerLocal(id));
            return;

        //If a player logs out (m = [id])
        case "logout":
            savePlayerSQL(loadPlayerLocal(id));
            return;
    }
}
```

Because the InOutPlayerc.Message m only contains an id for the different InOutPlayerc.Message.Type, I have to store the player local. So I can get the Player object back by giving the id.

```
public static void savePlayerLocal(int id, Player p){...};
public static Player loadPlayerLocal(int id){...};
```

Here is the rest of my functions:

```
public static Player loadPlayerSQL(string username)
{
    try
    {
        int timessaid;
        string status;
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Players WHERE Username = @Username";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                timessaid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Chat"]);
                status = reader["Status"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return new Player(username, status, timessaid);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new Player(username, "DEFAULT", 0);
    }
}

public static void addTimesTalked(Player p)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand())
        {
            p.Chat = p.Chat + 1;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Players SET Chat = @Chat WHERE Username = @Username";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", p.Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chat", p.Chat);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}

public static void savePlayerSQL(Player p)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Players SET Status = @Status, Chat = @Chat WHERE Username = @Username";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", p.Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", p.Status);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chat", p.Chat);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Now here are my problems:
- I'm getting a System.NullReferenceException at 'if(p.Status == "BANNED") {'. Is this piece of code called immediately without waiting for the Player object to be created with the MySQL data in the function before?
- Functions can be called at the same time, which creates MySQL commands at the same time.
- I want all MySQL queries handled. None should be skipped.

So I'm thinking of something asynchronous or a lock that waits before a new MySQL query can be handled?

I've just started learning C# and I find this part a bit hard how I could solve this.
Could somebody help me how I can solve these? Or even give a hint at what I should look for?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're passing "id" from your message.  Is "id" the same as "username"?  Are you able to attach a debugger and step through the code?  What exactly are you passing to your SQL?  Is it what you expect?  If you run the query directly in the db do you get what you expect back?  I suspect this isn't an async issue at all, rather that your query isn't returning what you think.

Comment: What does Message.getString(int) do?  My assumption is that it's grabbing the first string in the array, but it would be good if you included that code too so we can be sure of the behaviour.

Comment: Message.getString(int) does grab the first string in the array. It's from a library I downloaded and I'm really sure it has correct behaviour.

Id is not the same as username. Whenever a player logs in his account with username is linked to an id. However this id is randomly made when he logs in. So if he would log in tomorrow he has a different id then today. Only the login type message passes his username. All other type of messages (there are more then these) passes me his id he was linked to when he logged in. Therefore I need to save it so I can query it in MySQL.

I will try to debug now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If id and username aren't the same, then that's your problem.  Your SQL in loadPlayerSQL(string username) won't find your user because you're passing in the id instead of the username.